# MS Access Query In VB.NET 2008

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2013

The below code works in this way: When I enter data inside my textboxes, they go straight to my database and then if I click up button on the numeric up and down, it will give me empty textboxes to put data on again.

If I click on the down button in the numeric up and down, it will show me the previous data I entered in their respective textboxes. That's exactly what I have been wanting to do, but the problem is it only updates the database (obviously because of the UPDATE query) and overwrites the previously saved data.

Is there anyway that I can still achieve the same result (the one I mentioned about still being able to see the data I entered previously by the use of the numeric up and down) but the data previously stored in the database will not be overwritten?

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim tables As DataTableCollection
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Form2.ShowDialog()
    Form2.Dispose()
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.Click
    Label1.Text = "1"
    Button1.PerformClick()
End Sub
Private Sub RadioButton2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton2.Click
    Label1.Text = "2"
    Button1.PerformClick()
End Sub
Private Sub RadioButton3_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton3.Click
    Label1.Text = "3"
    Button1.PerformClick()
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton4_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton4.Click
    Label1.Text = "4"
    Button1.PerformClick()
End Sub

Public Sub clear()
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    TextBox3.Text = ""
    TextBox4.Text = ""
    TextBox5.Text = ""
    RadioButton1.Checked = False
    RadioButton2.Checked = False
    RadioButton3.Checked = False
    RadioButton4.Checked = False
    TextBox1.Select()
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    NumericUpDown1.Value = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex
    Dim dr As DataRow
    Dim i As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString, i) Then
        i = ComboBox1.SelectedValue - 1
    End If
    dr = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)
    TextBox1.Text = dr("Question").ToString
    TextBox2.Text = dr("Answer1").ToString
    TextBox3.Text = dr("Answer2").ToString
    TextBox4.Text = dr("Answer3").ToString
    TextBox5.Text = dr("Answer4").ToString
    Label1.Text = dr("RightAnswer").ToString
    Label8.Text = ComboBox1.Text
    If Label1.Text = "1" Then
        RadioButton1.Checked = True
    ElseIf Label1.Text = "2" Then
        RadioButton2.Checked = True
    ElseIf Label1.Text = "3" Then
        RadioButton3.Checked = True
    ElseIf Label1.Text = "4" Then
        RadioButton4.Checked = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con.Open()
    ds = New DataSet
    tables = ds.Tables
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Questions]", con)
    da.Fill(ds, "Questions")
    Dim view1 As New DataView(tables(0))
    With ComboBox1
        .DataSource = ds.Tables("Questions")
        .ValueMember = "ID"
        .DisplayMember = "ID"
        .SelectedIndex = 0
    End With
    con.Close()
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = NumericUpDown1.Value
    NumericUpDown1.Value = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex
    NumericUpDown1.Maximum = ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1
End Sub
Private Sub NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown1.ValueChanged
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = NumericUpDown1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    con.Open()
    Dim update_user As New Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("UPDATE Questions SET [Question]= @Q, [Answer1]= @A1, [Answer2]= @A2, [Answer3]= @A3, [Answer4]= @A4, [RightAnswer]= @RA WHERE ID = @ID;", con)
    update_user.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Q", TextBox1.Text)
    update_user.Parameters.AddWithValue("@A1", TextBox2.Text)
    update_user.Parameters.AddWithValue("@A2", TextBox3.Text)
    update_user.Parameters.AddWithValue("@A3", TextBox4.Text)
    update_user.Parameters.AddWithValue("@A4", TextBox5.Text)
    update_user.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RA", Label1.Text)
    update_user.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Label8.Text)
    update_user.ExecuteNonQuery()
    update_user.Dispose()
    con.Close()
    ds = New DataSet
    tables = ds.Tables
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Questions]", con)
    da.Fill(ds, "Questions")
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
    Button1.PerformClick()
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox2_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyUp
    Button1.PerformClick()
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox3_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox3.KeyUp
    Button1.PerformClick()
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox4_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox4.KeyUp
    Button1.PerformClick()
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox5_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox5.KeyUp
    Button1.PerformClick()
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Or TextBox4.Text = "" Or TextBox5.Text = "" Then
        NumericUpDown1.Enabled = False
        If NumericUpDown1.Value = NumericUpDown1.Value + 1 Then
            NumericUpDown1.Enabled = True
            NumericUpDown1.Value = NumericUpDown1.Value - 1
        End If
    Else
        NumericUpDown1.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Or TextBox4.Text = "" Or TextBox5.Text = "" Then
        NumericUpDown1.Enabled = False
        If NumericUpDown1.Value = NumericUpDown1.Value + 1 Then
            NumericUpDown1.Value = NumericUpDown1.Value - 1
        End If
    Else
        NumericUpDown1.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Or TextBox4.Text = "" Or TextBox5.Text = "" Then
        NumericUpDown1.Enabled = False
        If NumericUpDown1.Value = NumericUpDown1.Value + 1 Then
            NumericUpDown1.Value = NumericUpDown1.Value - 1
        End If
    Else
        NumericUpDown1.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox4_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox4.TextChanged
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Or TextBox4.Text = "" Or TextBox5.Text = "" Then
        NumericUpDown1.Enabled = False
        If NumericUpDown1.Value = NumericUpDown1.Value + 1 Then
            NumericUpDown1.Value = NumericUpDown1.Value - 1
        End If
    Else
        NumericUpDown1.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox5_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox5.TextChanged
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Or TextBox4.Text = "" Or TextBox5.Text = "" Then
        NumericUpDown1.Enabled = False
        If NumericUpDown1.Value = NumericUpDown1.Value + 1 Then
            NumericUpDown1.Value = NumericUpDown1.Value - 1
        End If
    Else
        NumericUpDown1.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Whoa. Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, what's wrong with my question?

Comment: Your question is not really about your code, but how to rewrite the code do something else.  I am curious what the difference is between a Dataset and a Tables collection.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but do not put words into my mouth. I am trying to verify if there is any way I can do what I need to do, I am not asking for anyone to REWRITE my code for me. Obviously, I have put a lot of hardwork in that code given the fact that I am new to VB. Did you even read my question @Plutonix?? Seems to me like you didn't. "Is there anyway that I can still achieve the same result (the one I mentioned about still being able to see the data I entered previously by the use of the numeric up and down) but the data previously stored in the database will not be overwritten?"

Comment: That was my question. It's a close-ended question meaning that it has to be answered by Yes or No. Did I say, "Can anyone please help me rewrite this code??" Get a grip. You're so rude

Comment: First, look into combining handlers on your methods. You have 5 exact pieces of code that could be combined into a single method that has multiple events assigned to it. Now, as far as your question, I think you need to determine if you went backwards and set a boolean "flag" to check against prior to performing the button_click that updates the data.

Comment: Hi @CharlesMay, I am not sure about the flag you were saying.. Sorry I am just really  new to VB

Comment: You stated when you move down, you move to the previous record. At this point you need to set something like a boolean (MovePrev) = true. Then before you run your update code you need to ensure that MovePrev is False before executing the udpate. You would probably set MovePrev to False when you run your clear method as that appears to be when you're adding a new record.